# PowerBI Auto Refresh

Tags: powerbi, azure-sql-database

Good Day

A client I am working with wants to use a PowerBI dashboard to display in their call centre with stats pulled from an Azure SQL Database.

Their **specific requirement** is that the dashboard automaticly refresh every minute between their operating hours (8am - 5pm).

I have been researching this a bit but can't find a definitive answer.

**Is it possible for PowerBI to automaticly refresh every 1min?**

Is it dependant on the type of license and/or the type of connection (DIRECTQUERY vs IMPORT)

Answer (score 1):

You can set a report to refresh on a direct query source, using the automatic report refresh feature.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-automatic-page-refresh

This will allow you to refresh the report every 1 minute or other defined interval. This is report only, not dashboards as it is desktop only.

When publishing to the service you will be limited to a minimum refresh of 30 mins, unless you have a dedicated capacity. You could add an A1 Power BI Embedded SKU and turn it on then off during business hours to reduce the cost. Which would work out around £200 per month.

Other options for importing data would be to set a Logic App or Power Automate task to refresh the dataset using an API call, for a lower level of frequency, say 5 mins. It would be best to optimise your query to return a small amount of pre aggregated data to the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Power Automate to schedule refresh your dataset more than 48 times a day. You can refresh it every minute with Power Automate, it looks like. I can also see that you may be able to refresh your dataset more frequently than that with other tools.

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing the data with 1 min frequency is not possible in PowerBI. If you are not using powerBI premium than you can schedule upto 8 times in a day, with the minimum gap of 15 minutes. If in case you are using PowerBI premium you are allowed to schedule 48 slots.

If you are not able to compromise with the above restrictions, then it might be worth to look into powerBI reports for streaming datasets. But then again there are some cons to that as well, like they work only with DirectQuery etc etc.

Comment: Yeah had a look at this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-real-time-streaming) and seems there are three RealTime options:
Push dataset
Streaming dataset
PubNub streaming dataset

Comment: For your use case, i think Push dataset might be the right one as it allows historical analysis. But without streaming dataset I don't think one can achieve near real time refresh in powerBI

Comment: @monte - Yes, but see Jon's comments about DirectQuery and
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-directquery-about#when-is-directquery-useful